# How to update an array in mongodb using the new C# API

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to update an  array in mongodb using the new C# API.
for exemple how to modify medecins:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "periode" : "Matin",
        "jour" : "Dimanche",
        "service" : "Neurologie"
    },
    "medecins" : [ 
        ObjectId("574ec788572e1d2d20f9c7e2"), 
        ObjectId("57471e2f572e1d366c056735")
    ]
}
```

here's my code it doesn't work :

```
 ObjectId[] id_medecins = new ObjectId[IdMedecins.list.Count];
                for(int i=0; i<IdMedecins.list.Count;i++)
                {
                    id_medecins[i] = ObjectId.Parse(IdMedecins.list[i].ToString());
                }
                MongoClient client = Model.connectionServer();
                var db = client.GetDatabase("GP");
                var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("horaire");
                var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", horaire_);
                var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
                .Set("medecins",id_medecins);
                var result = collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
                var resultMsg = result.Result.MatchedCount.ToString();
                if (result.Result.IsModifiedCountAvailable)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Modifié avec succès", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    Close();
                }
```

Comment: What do you want to update? I see medicine contains object ids.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: He wants to update only the field medecins. Useful when working with bigger documents in MongoDb,, you can only update a field set of the document ...

Comment: here's my code above, it doesn't work when it becomes to arrays